# ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved

Tags: squid

I'm running Squid as a proxy server on my system.

ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: /

```
Invalid URL
```

Some aspect of the requested URL is incorrect.

Some possible problems are:

```
Missing or incorrect access protocol (should be "http://" or similar)

Missing hostname

Illegal double-escape in the URL-Path

Illegal character in hostname; underscores are not allowed.
```

Your cache administrator is webmaster.

the url is work good

Comment: What is the url or format of the url you are trying to access?

Comment: hey the url i want it is gui of squid u have idea ?

Comment: I assuming you are looking for squid cachemgr. Check this out [https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/CacheManager/CacheObjectScheme]

Comment: Oops, page not found (404 error)

Comment: What did you do? what did you access